# Getting the first strings of lines from file in python

Tags: python, string, file, file-io, split

I am new to Python and so this may be easy question to ask but I really need help with this.  I have a sample file which has a following content:

Integer 1 3 5 7 9
Float 3.14 4.55 5.66
Double 4.35993 3.456 4.5555

Items in rows are separated by a single space. I would like to know how I can get  the first words, for example, "Integer" and "Double" from the file. This is my code that gets file content:

```
with open('sample.txt','r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
    print(data)
```

But I do not know how to print first strings of lines (Integer,Float or Double).If possible could you help me with this, please ? Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `readlines()` to read all the lines into a list and iterate over that list. `split()` with default parameter would split on whitespaces, returning a list type. Hence use index 0 to get the first item from the tokenized list.

```
with open('sample.txt','r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines()
        print(line.split()[0])
```

Comment: just use `for line in myfile:`... in this case, `myfile.readlines()` is completely useless since you are not storing the result and you might as well iterate over the file lazily line by line instead of eagerly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Agreed. Old habits die hard !

Comment: Thank you for your help ! One more question, please. As I have  those individuals now (Integer,Double, Float), how can I get specified item (such as Integer or Float)  ? @nitimalh

Comment: Not sure what you mean by getting specified item ? If you are looking to match you might want to look into doing a regex match ?!

Comment: No, actually I mean as I have beginnings of each lines now (i.e, Integer, Float,Double), how can I print specific one of them (for example, Integer). I tried print(line.split()[0][0]) but it did not work (

Comment: Calling split on  `"Integer 1 3 5 7 9".split()` yields a list (lets call it output) `["Integer", "1", "3", "5", "6", "9"]`. So index zero of the resulting list is the first word. This means output[0] yields 'Integer'. Apply the same logic to each line in your file as you iterate through it.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.readlines()
for d in data:
    print(d.split()[0])
```

---

- Use `readlines` to read line by line.
- `split()` splits each line by spaces.
- `[0]` takes the first index position, which is the word you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `.split()` and give what u want with help slice syntax.